# problems using replit with node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, nodes, replit

I recently started my backend studies at freecodecamp and to validate the tests they ask you to use the Replit website, but whenever I try to start the program, a message appears in the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF11Q.png)

Someone knows, how can i fix this?
I have tried use the command line

> npm install
> npm start

works for 5 seconds, then big back again
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBxK7.png)

Comment: Hi, @Patrick Almeida! Can you edit your question to include the error message as formatted text (as described here, under the heading "Complete": https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of as an image? This will make it easier for contributors to understand and answer your question.